# remove double quotes with regEx

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I need to remove `{ [] ""`

I'm using this regEx, but I can't figure out how to remove the double quotes:

```
var showBrackets:RegExp = new RegExp('\\[|\\]|}', "gi");
loadedText = loadedText.replace(showBrackets, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

For your regex, a single character class will do the job:

```
["{\[\]]
```

Pop that in to your existing code.